# Do I need to repeat requestLocationUpdates or just call it once?

Tags: android, location, android-jobscheduler, fusedlocationproviderapi

I want to get location of android user frequently in background using a JobService. I have implemented `FusedLocationApi` and I call `FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` to receive updates on user location. Do I need to call this JobService **frequently** (using JobScheduler e.g. every 30 seconds) or I should call it **just once** and the `requestLocationUpdates` repeats the task itself?

```
public class LocationMonitoringService extends JobService implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();
    boolean isWorking = false;
    boolean jobCancelled = false;
    GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
        mLocationClient.connect();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before being completed.");
        jobCancelled = true;
        boolean needsReschedule = isWorking;
        jobFinished(jobParameters, needsReschedule);
        return needsReschedule;
    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Google API");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "== location != null");
            //Send result to Server
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API");

    }
}
```

Comment: Job service have limitation. Do you need to update locations every 30 sec?

Comment: Yes I need every 30 seconds. I know there is Foreground service for this purpose. Please let me know if there are more options. @VadimEksler

Comment: It will be very expensive for battery using. you can't do it via JobService, just default service with showing notification all the time (Relevant to android 8 and bigger).